# Net::HTTP post with multiline param

Tags: ruby, net-http, multilinestring

I'd like to post a multiline param with Net::HTTP in Ruby. I tried adding \n or \r\n in the param string but it just arrives at destination as \n or \r\n.

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://mysite.com/post/uri'),{'param'=>'value','multiline_data'=>'data_line1\ndata_line2'})
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line feeds in URL's are usually encoded as %0D%0A. You need to break your sentences using this to receive a multi line input on the other end.

Comment: Doesn't work (or i'm doing it wrong). It arrives as 'data_line1%0D%0Adata_line2'

Comment: You may also need to URI.unescape(params[:multiline_data])